# Difference between plasmids and gene tonics?

Tags: bioshock

Plasmids and gene tonics appear to both come in a bottle and function the same way. Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Plasmids

*Active Plasmids require [EVE](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/EVE) for use, while passive Plasmids, called Gene Tonics, provide an effect merely by being equipped.* Plasmid bottles are recognizable by their deep red color.

[image: Plasmid bottle]

Plasmids are found, obtained, or bought with [ADAM](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/ADAM) throughout the course of BioShock. Jack has a limited number of Plasmid Slots for actively equipped Plasmids, and his currently equipped Plasmids can be changed at a Gene Bank.

[List of Plasmids in BioShock](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Plasmids#Plasmids_in_BioShock)

#### Gene Tonics

*While active Plasmids require [EVE](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/EVE) for use, Tonics provide an effect merely by being equipped.*

In BioShock, Jack is able to choose from a vast selection of Tonics to equip. With Tonic Slot upgrades, the player can equip up to eighteen Tonics, which can be swapped at a Gene Bank. Tonics have three classifications, Combat, Engineering and Physical Tonics and only six Tonics per classification may be equipped at one time. Tonics are found in Rapture or purchased at Gatherer's Gardens.

A Combat, Engineering, and a Physical Tonic bottle, respectively:
[image: Combat gene tonic bottle] [image: Engineering gene tonic bottle] [image: Physical gene tonic bottle]

[List of Gene Tonics in BioShock](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Gene_Tonics#Combat_Tonics)

---

<sup>Source: BioShock Wiki — [Gene Tonic](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Gene_Tonic), [BioShock Gene Tonics](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Gene_Tonics), [Plasmid](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Plasmid), [BioShock Plasmids](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Plasmids) articles (emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Plasmids are active skills that you can equip. You must use them, and each use costs a certain amount of EVE.

Gene Tonics are passive skills. You can't use/cast them, they are always active as long as they are equipped. They tend to boost your stats, make hacking easier, or a number of other things.

Comment: Don't you mean that Plasmids require a certain amount of EVE, not ADAM?

Comment: @Keavon Yes, you are correct. Been a while since I played BioShock. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for pointing that out. :)